# How can I use MathJax/Latex to typeset equations on this site?

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed

Engineering.SE supports [$\LaTeX$](http://www.latex-project.org/) style equation editing via [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/).  However, most of the guides for typesetting equations with $\LaTeX$ are either too limited or too expansive for new users who just want to ask their question.  This post will aim to give a simple introduction to the most commonly used features of equation typesetting.  Below are also some links to other guides.

---

### Other Guides

#### Limited

- [Markdown Editing Help: LaTeX](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex)
- [When should I use math markup?](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/178/368)

#### Expansive

- [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
- [An Introduction to Using TeX in the
  Harvard Mathematics Department](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/)

Answer (score 13):

### The Basics

- **Inline equations** are surrounded by dollar signs; `$\sin(x)$` gives $\sin(x)$.
- **Equations on their own line** are surrounded by double dollar signs; `$$\tan(\theta)=o/a$$` gives $$\tan(\theta)=o/a$$
- **Subscripts and superscripts** are denoted by the `_` and `^` operators; `E_i^2` gives $E_i^2$
- **Brackets** can be used to extend the influence of operators over multiple characters; `E_{1,2}^{op}` gives $E_{1,2}^{op}$
- **Fractions** can be made with the `\frac{}{}` command; `\frac{\partial E}{\partial z}` gives $\frac{\partial E}{\partial z}$. If your inline fraction is compressed into too small a space, try using `\dfrac` to force the fraction to display as if it were on its own line; `\dfrac{\partial E}{\partial z}` gives $\dfrac{\partial E}{\partial z}$.
- **Spaces and carriage returns** have no meaning; `\alpha\beta     \gamma` gives $\alpha\beta     \gamma$

---

### Common Symbols

Common symbols such as Greek letters are generally rendered by a slash followed by the name.  For symbols with both an uppercase and lowercase form the case of the first letter determines the case of the symbol.

- **Greek letters (lower):** `\alpha \beta \gamma \delta \epsilon \zeta \eta \theta \iota \kappa \lambda \mu \nu \xi \omicron \pi \rho \sigma \tau \upsilon \phi \chi \psi \omega` gives $\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\zeta\eta\theta\iota\kappa\lambda\mu\nu\xi\omicron\pi\rho\sigma\tau\upsilon\phi\chi\psi\omega$
- **Greek letters (upper):** `\Gamma \Delta \Theta \Lambda \Xi \Pi \Sigma \Upsilon \Phi \Psi \Omega` gives $\Gamma \Delta \Theta \Lambda \Xi \Pi \Sigma \Upsilon \Phi \Psi \Omega$. Other uppercase Greek letters can be made by simply typing the corresponding letter in the Latin alphabet, e.g. A for upper case alpha.
- **Basic Integrals:** use `\int` where limits are added with the superscript and subscript operators; `\int_a^b xdx` gives $\int_a^b xdx$.
- **Multiple Integrals:** use `\iint` and `\iiint` for double and triple integrals when you don't need to specify separate limits; `\iint_A f(x, y) dxdy` gives $\iint_A f(x, y) dxdy$
- **Pretty Integrals:** optionally, use `\limits` to position the limits of an integral directly above and below the integral symbol and `\,` to separate terms like $dx$ and $dy$ from the function and each other; `\int\limits_a^b\int\limits_c^d f(x,y)\,dx\,dy` gives $\int\limits_a^b\int\limits_c^d f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$
- **Radicals:** use `\sqrt{}` which will expand to the size of its argument; `\sqrt{a}` gives $\sqrt{a}$, `\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}` gives $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}$, etc.
- **Relations:** `\lt \gt \leq \geq \neq` gives $\lt\gt\leq\geq\neq$
- **Operators:** `\times \div \pm \mp \cdot` gives $\times\div\pm\mp\cdot$
- **Approximately:** `\approx \sim \simeq \propto` gives $\approx \sim \simeq \propto$
- **Special:** `\infty \nabla \partial \Im \Re` gives $\infty \nabla \partial \Im \Re$
- **Special Functions:** `\sin \cos \exp \ln \log` gives $\sin \cos \exp \ln \log$

---

### Parentheses

- **Ordinary parentheses,** brackets, and curly braces are added with the symbols `( ) [ ] | | \{ \}` (which gives $( ) [ ] | | \{ \}$).  Note that the curly braces needs the `\` since it is otherwise a special LaTeX symbol.
- **Expanding parentheses** can be added with the `\left` and `\right` commands;  `\exp [ \sin ( \frac{a}{b} ) ]` gives $$\exp [ \sin ( \frac{a}{b} ) ]$$ while `\exp \left[ \sin \left( \frac{a}{b} \right) \right]` gives $$\exp \left[ \sin \left( \frac{a}{b} \right) \right]$$

---

### Formatting Tips

- **Newlines are ignored unless escaped with `\\`.** For example:

  ```
  $$1
  2
  3$$
  ```

  $$1
  2
  3$$

  Versus:

  ```
   $$1\\
  2\\
  3$$
  ```

  $$1\\
  2\\
  3$$
- **Be careful when using the Blockquote button** (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>) in the editor window to format MathJax markup; the default behavior is to wrap the quote in a way that can result in undesired angle brackets in the rendered output. Take this formula as an example:

  $$\dfrac {\partial \mathbf u} {\partial t} + \mathbf u \cdot \nabla \mathbf u - \nu \nabla ^2 \mathbf u = - \nabla w + \mathbf g$$

  Highlighting the exact same marked-up formula in the editor window and pressing the Blockquote button produces this output:

  > $$\dfrac {\partial \mathbf u} {\partial t} + \mathbf u \cdot \nabla
  >  > \mathbf u - \nu \nabla ^2 \mathbf u = - \nabla w + \mathbf g$$

  Notice the extra $>$ that now appears in the second term. To avoid this, make sure to use only a single Blockquote delimiter (`>`) at the start of the MathJax block (`$` or `$$`).
- **Sometimes it's more effective to consolidate several formulas or equations** into a single block of MathJax-formatted text than to scatter them throughout the body of a post. In these cases, you can use `\tag{}` to number or label a block of MathJax markup for later reference:

  $\tag{1} C = 2 \pi r$
  $\tag{2} A = \pi r^2$
  $\tag{3} V = {4 \over 3} \pi r^3$

  A more detailed explanation, including labeled hyperlink references, is available [here on Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11491/126785).